# EF Core 2.0 Setting up DB Context first time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I have a new asp.net core 2.0 project and I trying to get my db context stored to the db via way of migrations now I have the dependencies installed via NuGet that should be there.

[image]

This is my DBContext

```
public  class SolitudeDBContext : DbContext
{
    public SolitudeDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
    public virtual DbSet<OrderHeader> OrderHeader { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schema: SchemaName.Portal);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {        
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My Appsettings where I store my Default connection.

```
 {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-JHIMUM4\\SQLEXPRESS2014;Database=solitude;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },

"Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": false,
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning"
  }
}
}
```

I have been using

> PM> dotnet ef migrations add firstDatabase
>
> But the following error is thrown even though you can see the
>   references are installed also in models I have the item group fixed as
>   well. dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef" At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + dotnet ef migrations add firstDatabase
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (No executable f...and "dotnet-ef":String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

My project file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Models\products\" />
    <Folder Include="Models\stock\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Projects after second edit:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Models\products\" />
    <Folder Include="Models\stock\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: You're in the package manager console, `dotned` is a [command window instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations). Or follow [this walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db).

Comment: @GertArnold that guide is for .net core I am using .net core 2 there are differences

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` as a `DotNetCliToolReference` instead of a package reference. This will make the `dotnet-ef` commands available:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I am still getting the above errror

Comment: i added the amended file and edit up above i still getting the same error

Comment: Did you run `dotnet restore` first?